# Why does express-session create a session with every wget request to it?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, express-rate-limit

I decided to test with wget and it turns out that you can clog the session store if you simply spam with wget, i.e. the store simply creates very, very many sessions of small size, but a lot of them. How can I avoid this?

I have two scenarios in my head.

1. Reduce the maximum age of sessions.
2. Set the rate-limit.

But I'm not sure that's enough. What do you recommend?

Less than 5 minutes of attack if wget is called every 0.1 seconds.
[image]

*Note*: this only happens if you use a tool like wget. If you refresh the page in your browser, no new session will be created.

Code example:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const path = require('path')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret:'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie:{
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 14 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // two week
  },
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'something secret' })

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('trust proxy', 1)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.session)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I just hadn't read the documentation to the end. To not create a session every time you just need to set "saveUninitialized: false". Then the session will be created only when the user, for example, finds the site, or just something happens with the session.

But if you have more ideas, then tell me.